# Animation in plotly.js 3D scatter plot

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

I've created a 3D scatter plot and would like to animate the data. I followed the procedure mentioned in the document. But the plot just changes the data without any animation. I've searched for similar questions, couldn't find any. This issue seems to be present only in 3d scatter plot. What is the way around this issue ?

Comment: Please add a [MCVE] to your question. Otherwise we can only guess what might be the problem.

Comment: please check the following pen
https://codepen.io/pbshgthm/pen/OZvbxV?editors=1111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plotly.js does not support animation on scatter3D as of now.